# NoSuchMessageException - Spring ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource vs ResourceBundleMessageSource

Tags: java, spring

I defined the following Spring bean:

```
<bean id="messageSource" 
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:messages</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The controller:

```
@Controller
public class EuserController {

    @Inject
    MessageSource messageSource;

    @RequestMapping(value="/euser/{empId}", method=RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public @ResponseBody String deleteEeuserById(@PathVariable(value="empId") Integer id) {
        return messageSource.getMessage("deleteEuser.success", null, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());
    }
}
```

And it works fine. But when I'm trying to replace:

```
org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource
```

with:

```
org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource
```

and I get a `org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException`.

What does this happen when using the `org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource` instead?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.html) is an alternative to [`ResourceBundleMessageSource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ResourceBundleMessageSource.html) that is capable of refreshing the messages while the application is running. It's also more powerful as you are not limited to bundles on the classpath but you can load files from other locations too.

When using a `ResourceBundleMessageSource` you need to restart your application when making changes as `ResourceBundleMessageSource` doesn't reload your bundles when you change them. The `classpath:` prefix also needs to be removed. This is because of the way the two classes work:

- The `ResourceBundleMessageSource` uses a JDK class to do its thing: [`ResourceBundle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html). It delegates to it to load the bundle. Basically, the bundle you give to `ResourceBundleMessageSource` must conform to what `ResourceBundle` expects and processes. `ResourceBundle` does not know how to handle the `classpath:` prefix and so it fails.
- `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` on the other hand is "smarter" and knows how to load bundles from other places, not just the classpath. It works with a Spring class: [`Resource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/Resource.html). [There are various implementations out of the box](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-implementations). When you give a bundle to `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource`, since it can load files from various places, you have to be explicit with the location and say "My file is on the classpath". [You say that by adding the `classpath:` prefix and Spring knows how to handle it](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-resourceloader).

Comment: Yeah, you were absolutely right. Thank you. But why is the classpath keyword so important here?

Comment: @user3663882: I added some more details to my answer.